# What does the underscore mean before a variable in Swiftui in an init()?

Tags: swift, swiftui

What does the underscore mean before momentDate?  Why is it needed?

[image]

Comment: Please paste actual code, not a screenshot of code.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The underscored variable name refers to the underlying storage for the [`Binding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) struct. This is part of a language feature called [Property Wrappers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties/#Property-Wrappers).

Given one variable declaration, `@Binding var momentDate: Date`, you can access three variables:

- `self._momentDate` is the `Binding<Date>` struct itself.
- `self.momentDate`, equivalent to `self._momentDate.wrappedValue`, is a `Date`. You would use this when rendering the date in the view's body.
- `self.$momentDate`, equivalent to `self._momentDate.projectedValue`, is also the `Binding<Date>`. You would pass this down to child views if they need to be able to change the date.

For `Binding`, the "projected value" (`$`) is just `self`, and the difference between `_` and `$` is only in the [access level](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/accesscontrol/). However, other property wrappers may project a different type of value (see the `@SmallNumber` example in the [language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties/#Projecting-a-Value-From-a-Property-Wrapper)).

Comment: Very well explained, thank you.

Comment: When something is so well explained, there are no more comments :-)

Comment: Very clear, thanks!

Comment: This comment is very helpful but I cannot find an explanation specifically mentioning the underscore syntax (e.g. ```_somePropery```) anywhere in the documentation. Your note "self._momentDate is the Binding<Date> struct itself." is the only information I can find on this. I am curious how this works internally. Is the underscore the only syntax available ? nothing similar to ```someProperty.wrapperItself``` ?

Comment: The underscores are mentioned (albeit a bit indirectly) in this documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617

Answer (score 1):

[Official Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties/#Property-Wrappers)

A Binding is one of various Property Wrappers.

When you use a `@PropertyWrapper` on a `var`, it synthesizes convenience code.

That includes automatically creating a private var named `_yourPropVar`, whose type is `YourPropertyWrapper` (e.g. `Binding`).

When you prefix that with underscore, you're referencing the synthesized private variable - the Property Wrapper itself.

When you reference `yourPropVar` instead, without the `underscore`, it's accessing the synthesized wrapped value getter instead.