# SwiftUI: ColorScheme and init()

Tags: swift

im working on simple iOS app and there's a reason why I **have to** use `init()` section.
for i.e.:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var newName: String
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    init(){
        newName = "test"
    }
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            TextField("Sample TextField", text: $newName)
        }
    }
}
```

everything works just fine until I add `@Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme: ColorScheme`

I instantly get quite strange error "Variable 'self.newName' used before being initialized"

what am I missing?

Comment: If I add `= ""` to give newName an initial value then the error in init() goes away. Don’t ask me why.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the answer. but, that’s right, I already tried this. But if you launch app in simulator you’ll see nothing inside Textfeld, while we’re waiting to see “test” inside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, in this case you can initialise your `@State` parameter the way its mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65209375/2480304)

`_newName = State(initialValue: "test")`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to declare properties inside Struct or a Class:

1- **Optional Properties**: These properties doesn't required initial value during initialisation of Struct or Class, we can declare it using question-mark on type: @State var newName: String?

2- **Non-Optional Properties**: These properties must required initial value during initialisation of Struct or Class, we can declare it like this: @State var newName: String

So in your case you are using Non-Optional property, so you must need to provide either a default value to your newName: **@State var newName: String = ""** or pass a value for newName in the constructor of your Struct: **ContentView(newName: "Okeyman")**, you don't need to add init(){ } because Struct will automatically do this for you.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var newName: String
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            TextField("Sample TextField", text: $newName)
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this

```
ContentView(newName: "Okeyman")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this :)
But there is a reason why I **need** to use init(), which is not important in this context(i.e. CoreData). I just removed everything else for simplification.